# Tap Gesture on UILabel stops working after showing keyboard and moving frame

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` along with a `UILabel` submit button that is anchored to the bottom of my view.  When the user presses on the `UITextView` I added a keyboard listener to shift the frame of the keyboard and `UILabel` up above the keyboard.  The problem is that the Tap **Gesture recognizer** stops recognizing taps as soon as the keyboard appears.  It works perfectly before that.  Looking for help on how to fix.

Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var center: NSNotificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    center.addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    center.addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

    //Comments TextView
    var commentText = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(5,5,self.view.frame.width * 0.65, 30))
    commentText.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    commentText.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    commentText.editable = true
    commentText.text = "Write a Comment..."
    mainSV.addSubview(commentText)

    //Submit button
    var submitTF = UILabel(frame:CGRectMake(commentText.frame.maxX, 0, self.view.frame.width - commentText.frame.maxX - 30, 30))
    submitTF.text = "Send"
    submitTF.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
    submitTF.enabled = false
    submitTF.userInteractionEnabled = true

    var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:Selector("submitTap:"))
    submitTF.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}


func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    commentText.text=""
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,-150,320,460)
}
```